# Any cucumber Before and After hook at a feature level

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber-jvm, rest-assured

i have gone through many help, but all are about explaining on scenario level. Is there any Before and After hook at feature level for cucumber JVM.? This page [cucumber Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23113370/is-there-a-cucumber-hook-to-run-before-and-after-each-feature) tells about ruby language, but can i get help for java?

Comment: it's a good question. I don't understand why the downvotes, but anyway.
It's not currently possible, or anytime soon from what I can tell.
See https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/1321

Answer (score 0):

The following contains many of the avialable hooks:
http://zsoltfabok.com/blog/2012/09/cucumber-jvm-hooks/

Similar to junit it appears there is an annotationo for @Before and @After

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber does not support hooks on feature levels like specflow having @BeforeFeature and @AfterFeature tags. This is open issue https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/issues/515

Comment: `@BeforeAll` and `@AfterAll` do exist these days.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me in Java Cucumber.  What is not totally clear in the Cucumber documentation is that you can Tag a Feature; and that will tag all Scenarios in the Feature.  This allows you to use the Tag Expression on the After and Before tags to make them run only for the Scenarios within a particular Feature.
ex.

```
@UserServiceEventSubmissionARTSClaimInquiryHooks
Feature: Service Event Submission - ARTS Robot - Claim Inquiry
  Scenario: Temporary scenario for a Claim Inquiry
  ...

@After("@UserServiceEventSubmissionARTSClaimInquiryHooks")
public void afterScenarioDocumentation(Scenario scenario){
    if (callDetailProducerSubmission != null) {
       ...
```