# After hook for each feature in cucumber java

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber

In cucucmber i want to run a step after all the scenarios in a feature are run, can I have an after hook for the each feature.
I want to have an after Hooks in cucumber java.
Please help.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46734174/any-cucumber-before-and-after-hook-at-a-feature-level

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is nan "After Hook" in cucumber. You can use just `after` and it will do the job.

Comment: Hi Sai, it would be a better formatting if you distinguish @after using a text background highlight or using Bold style. Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

In Cucumber 7 or later versions we have the **@BeforeAll** and **@AfterAll** hooks.

1. **@BeforeAll**: This will run before all the scenarios.
2. **@AfterAll**: This will run after all the scenarios.

In this [blog post](https://qatestauto.com/beforeall-and-afterall-hooks-in-cucumber-7-ater-versions/), you can see the demonstration and signature of these hooks.